# How to make R take values from another column in case of missing values?

Tags: r, merge

I have two tables with data with people leaving a company from different data sources. In one column for leaving date there are some missing values and in these cases I want to take the dates from the other table.

The columns in the two tables look like this:

```
  ID      exit1      exit2
1  1        N/A 31/01/2016
2  2 01/02/2016 01/01/2021
3  3 01/10/2010 30/09/2019
4  4        N/A 31/12/2015
5  5 01/01/2016 30/09/2020
```

I want my result to be like this:

```
  ID      exit1
1  1 31/01/2016
2  2 01/02/2016
3  3 01/10/2010
4  4 31/12/2015
5  5 01/01/2016
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(exit1 = na_if(exit1, "N/A")) %>%
   transmute(ID, exit1 = coalesce(exit1, exit2))
```

-output

```
 ID      exit1
1  1 31/01/2016
2  2 01/02/2016
3  3 01/10/2010
4  4 31/12/2015
5  5 01/01/2016
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, exit1 = c("N/A", "01/02/2016", "01/10/2010", 
"N/A", "01/01/2016"), exit2 = c("31/01/2016", "01/01/2021", "30/09/2019", 
"31/12/2015", "30/09/2020")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(exit1 = ifelse(exit1=="N/A", exit2, exit1), .keep="unused")
```

```
 ID      exit1
1  1 31/01/2016
2  2 01/02/2016
3  3 01/10/2010
4  4 31/12/2015
5  5 01/01/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using basic `R`:

```
df$exit1[is.na(df$exit1)] = df$exit2[is.na(df$exit1)]
```

and if the value is the actual string `"N/A"`:

```
df$exit1[df$exit1 == 'N/A'] = df$exit2[df$exit1 == 'N/A']
```

and to keep the desired columns:

```
df = df[,c('ID', 'exit1')]
```